# Counting nodes in binary tree

Tags: java, count, binary-tree, nodes

I am having trouble counting the nodes in my binary tree. It is a real simple tree to start as illustrated in the diagram below.

```
                                (5)
                       (3)-------^-------(7)
                  (2)---^---(6)           ^-------(9)
                       (5)---^---(8)
```

I added eight nodes so there should be 8. However when I run my code it counts 7 nodes. I think it is just counting all the left nodes and the right nodes and not counting the root but  I set the number of nodes to 1 to count the root before it counts the left and right nodes. See the code below

```
private int getNumNodes(Node<E> root){
        numNodes = 1; // starts by counting the root

        // counts the left nodes
        if(root.left != null){
            numNodes += getNumNodes(root.getLeft());
        }

        // counts the right nodes
        if(root.right != null){
            numNodes += getNumNodes(root.getRight());
        }               
    return numNodes;
}

public int getNumNodes(){
    return root == null ? 0 : getNumNodes(root);
}
```

It must be missing a count somewhere but I am not sure where it is happening. Could you guys please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: I wonder what `close (1/5)` means.

Comment: @jdb no, it should be a local variable instead of a class member

Comment: @Eng.Fouad 1 of 5 close votes ..

Comment: @pst ah, makes sense. The old style was `close (1)`.

Comment: If your first check is to see if "root" is null (and return 0 if so), then you can eliminate all other null checks reducing your code by about 1/2.  in fact, the whole thing can become one line: return root==null?null:getNumNodes(root.left)+getNumNodes(root.right);

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem is that `numNodes` is a class member when it should be a local variable of the method.

Comment: +1 seems right, Also note that the code fails if given null as input